# PHP: Best way to write a Class where its functions can be added infinitely "as you go"?

Tags: php, scripting, programming-languages

Right now I have a normal class like this

```
class MyClass
{
   function myfunc1 () { }
   function myfunc2 () { }
}
```

However the filesize of `MyClass` is becoming large as I add more functions along the way.
Everytime I use MyClass, only selected functions will be used by each individual application.

What is the best way to minimize the filesize of `MyClass`?
Is it advisable to separate each functions in a separate file, and just include them if they're needed? If yes, how do you implement it in terms of code?

Comment: why not to use overloading and make classes project oriented?

Comment: It sounds like you have one big monolithic class that does too many things. Also: Namespaces may be worth a look.

Comment: We should maintain SRP in our code.

Please read this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401657/how-to-avoid-srp-chaos][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401657/how-to-avoid-srp-chaos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Infinitely growing classes generally lead to [god objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), which are considered an anti-pattern in OO software development. When designing a class, first think about what this class is supposed to do for you, then you can design it's interface (aka public methods). If you have a good design, it's unlikely your class grows by much later on. If it does, it's time for a refactorization and breaking the class into smaller pieces.

Comment: Also, the God object can be effectively avoided by following the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Answer (score 2):

You want to split functionality up in different classes and files. For example, have 1 file per class, and have a single class have a clear purpose instead of one big god class.

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't use several files for the same class. If the class is getting to big to manage, it's likely that you should be using subclasses.